# Least number of local trivializations of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $\pi: E \to X$ be a real or complex vector bundle over $X$ of rank $r$. Then there exist finitely many local trivializations of $E$, i.e. there exists an open covering $(U_j)_{j=1}^k$ and homeomorphisms $h_j : \pi^{-1}(U_j) \to U_j \times \mathbb{K}^r$ such that $\pi(h_j^{-1}(x,v)) = x$ for $j=1, \ldots, k$.

Is there a name for the least such $k$, i.e. the least number of local trivializations required for the vector bundle? Also, are there some references looking into this concept?

Comment: [This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94479/does-every-vector-bundle-allow-a-finite-trivialization-cover) may be useful.

Comment: Maybe this is mentioned in the linked MO question, but an early reference for this is James' "On category, in the sense of Lusternik-Schnirelman", where this quantity you're describing is denoted $\operatorname{vecat}$ and compared to other notions of category.